# В font-face отрабатывают не все шрифты

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, шрифты

Здравствуйте возникла такая проблема, через font-face почему-то отрабатывают не все шрифты. Шрифты находятся в одной папке, они одного формата ttf и они кирилические.
Например это не работает:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Aksent";
    src: url("fonts/acs.ttf");
}
TH {
    background-color: #0078d7;
    font: 14pt 'Aksent';
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
TD {
    background-color: white;
    font: 15pt 'Aksent';
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

А это работает:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "a_RewinderDemi";
    src: url("fonts/REWI_D.TTF");
}
TH {
    background-color: #0078d7;
    font: 14pt 'a_RewinderDemi';
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
TD {
    background-color: white;
    font: 15pt 'a_RewinderDemi';
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Это проверено на многих шрифтах, какие то работают а другие нет.
При этом если шрифт установить в систему и записать без font-face то все работает.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае код более чем достаточен:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pressstart2p/v5/8Lg6LX8-ntOHUQnvQ0E7o6VKeqlTLmz9wgW802Ijrr8.woff2) format('woff2');
}

h1{
 font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
 }
```

```html
<h1>Тест</h1>
```

Не работать это все может только в двух случаях:

1) Нет файла или не правильный путь к нему. Проверяется наличием ошибок `not found` в инструментах разработчика <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>i</kbd>

2) Ваш браузер не поддерживает формат шрифта. Проверяется с помощью [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf)

Comment: Насчёт пути к файлу, все файлы находятся в одном и том же каталоге. И в пути меняется только имя файла. Как путь может быть неправильный? Если этой путь не правильный, то как тогда быть, что писать в пути?) А насчет каниуса спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: Ой, а формат шрифта ведь один и тот же всегда у меня - ttf. И он поддерживается firefox'ом моим.

Comment: Гугловские шрифты понятно что будут работать. Извиняюсь, Вы не могли бы у себя попробовть мои два шрифта. Вот [ссылка на архив](https://yadi.sk/d/OMsV_apR3GtqsK).

Comment: Что-то я сразу не догадался посмотреть в отладчике там следуэщие ошибки:

Comment: Что-то я сразу не догадался посмотреть в отладчике, там следующие 4 ошибки: downloadable font: bad search range (font-family: "Aksent" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
downloadable font: bad range shift (font-family: "Aksent" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
downloadable font: cmap: Range glyph reference too high (65535 > 198) (font-family: "Aksent" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Aksent" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0).

Comment: При этом если шрифт установить, то браузер его нормально воспринимает.